# Abount DNS configuration in CPanel, Please help me

Tags: web, dns, subdomain, cpanel

I want to ask about cPanel, i have asked by my customer, they used cPanel as website control panel, so the case like this.

my client have cPanel WHM, their domain's name  myClient.com can controled by cPanel, currently they have one exsisting website hosting at www.existingMyClient.com, so they want to make subdomain for example oldsite.myClient.com, which display the content of www.existingMyClient.com,

so, what i must configure in cPanel for that purpose ?

Comment: This question should be moved to serverfault.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Parked Domains on Cpanel of account existingMyClient.com
2. Create a parked domain oldsite.myClient.com

This parked subdomain (or domain) point to existingMyClient.com

Comment: Thanks for your answer, 

when i have added new parked domain,named is odlsite.myclinet.com, it'll listed in parked domain table, and in table of list, there's column Document Root, i know the Document Root column contain where content for odlsite.myclinet.com, but in my case the existingMyClient.com have been deployed in another server from server which installed cPanel